# How to run a command in node-red node exec to enable a script for LCD

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-red

I have a script to bring a current time on LCD in Raspberry PI.

LCD is connected with Raspberry PI tested working fine.

I created a script name index.js inside ~/.node-red folder, and have installed LCD node module inside the same ~/.node-red folder using command : `npm install lcd --save`

```
cd ~/.node-red
pi@raspberrypi ~/.node-red $ sudo node index.js
```

When I tested inside using the command it brings the time on the LCD.

How to execute this index.js script in node-red node exec?

I have tried but does not work.

[node-red connection picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dC72b.png)

[node exec config picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bSbj7.png)

In inject node I entered string 1 as payload

In exec node I entered command: `sudo /home/pi/.node-red/node index.js`

I tried in many ways to execute but no luck,

please check the pictures and help me in this issue.

Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the exec config node

- Change the command to just `/usr/bin/sudo`
- Uncheck the append message.payload
  box
- Place the following in the extra input parameters: `node /home/pi/.node-red/index.js`

You don't need to put your index.js in the .node-red directory but since it's there this should work.

Comment: hi, thanks for your reply. i will try this and give an update.