# How to use exec node on beaglebone green wireless to run c/c++ code

Tags: beagleboneblack, node-red

What needs to be typed into the 'Command' text field in the node-red 'exec' node to run a compiled c++ file at `/var/lib/cloud9/projectDirectory` and get the output of the 'cout' command in my c++ program?

Answer (score 0):

Here's what ended up working for me.

**ASSUMPTIONS**

You have a compiled c++ file at a directory you can locate.

**TLDR - Answer to my own question**

1. Locate the file path to the compiled c++ file.
   I was using Cloud9, so mine looked something like this:
   `/var/lib/cloud9/projectDirectory/`
2. Identify the command to run the c++ file.
   I had compiled mine by navigating to the projectDirectory from terminal and typing `g++ ain0.cpp -o ain0`. So to run this I would type `./ain0` in terminal from within projectDirectory.
3. Configure the 'exec' node.
   Place `/usr/bin/sudo` in the 'Command' field(I learned this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33222875/how-to-run-a-command-in-node-red-node-exec-to-enable-a-script-for-lcd#)).
   Uncheck the option to 'Append' the msg.payload.
   Place `/var/lib/cloud9/projectDirectory/./ain0` in the 'Append' text field.
4. Done!

The above steps allowed me to use a debug node (and later, an MQTT node) connected to the first (top-most) output of the 'exec' node to capture the values passed to 'cout' in my c++ program. If you read through the info for the 'exec' node, you'll notice that it requires an input to trigger the execution. I connected an 'inject' node and set it to output a string value of 'true'. I played with this a little, and found that it didn't seem to matter what the 'inject' was sending to the 'exec' node. A value of Boolean worked just the same for me.